# Convert a Java Method object to a Function object

Tags: java, enums, method-reference

In a Java 11 application, I have an enum with a basic mapping method:

```
public enum MyEnum{

    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3;

    public static MyEnum fromString(String s)
    {
        //Return the Enum based on s.
        ...
    }
}
```

This method is essentially a `Function<String,MyEnum>` and can be referenced by `MyEnum::fromString`.

The application scans the classpath for all Enums (there are multiple), and gives a `List<Class> enumClasses` to some processor class. Note that all the classes in this list are of course Enums. The processor tries to find th mapping method and execute it:

```
public Class Processor{

    public void process(String s){
       List<Class> enumClasses = ... //scan for Enums;

       enumClasses.stream()
                  .map(enumClass -> enumClass::fromString(s))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }    
}
```

The goal here is to get a list of of Enum values (instead of classes) based on the given String. This snippet doesn't work because the compiler doesn't know all my classes have this fromString() method reference.

There are some ways to make this work which I want to avoid:

- Make all enums implement a common interface (with a `fromString()` method), then scan for enums with this interface and cast them so the mthod reference be resolve.
- Use reflection to search for a Method with specific name or exactly one String argument and an Enum return type.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

1. In the `MyEnum` class I want to annotate the `fromString()` method with a custom annotation like `@FromStringFunction`.
2. The Processor checks if the class X has a method that is annotated ith this annotation.
3. If it finds such a method, it somehow "knows" that this method is actually a `Function<String,X>`
4. It can then pass this Function to the whatever method that needs this Function so it can apply it.

The problem lies with step 3: the method is an object of type `Method` and I can't find a clean, easy way to tell the Processor class "Hey buddy, don't worry! If I annotated this method with @FromStringFunction, you have my word that it is actually a Function that takes a string as input and returns an enum constant".

Is this feasible?

Comment: No.  A common interface or reflection are your only options.